# Which covid-19 vaccines have suspected cases of thrombosis?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination

As far as I know, Astrazeneca, Moderna, Pfizer and Johnson & Johnson have suspected cases of
thrombosis.

[U.S. Recommends Pausing Use Of Johnson & Johnson Vaccine Over Blood Clot Concerns](https://www.npr.org/sections/coronavirus-live-updates/2021/04/13/986709618/u-s-recommends-pausing-use-of-johnson-johnson-vaccine-over-blood-clot-concerns)

[Moderna and Pfizer also registered some case of thrombosis.](https://www.menshealth.com/es/salud-bienestar/a35875084/pfizer-moderna-caso-trombosis/)

How about the others? (Sputnik V, Sinopharm, Sinovac, etc.)

Which covid-19 vaccines have suspected cases of thrombosis?

Comment: Almost a billion doses (>800 M) of all the vaccines have been given so far and there have been a handful of thrombosis problems reported following vaccination. That really can't be more than the baseline level of such problems with or without a vaccine. Just my opinion, but I don't think there's credible evidence that any of the vaccines have a thrombosis problem.

Comment: @CareyGregory I agree with you. However, is it known why the medical authorities in these countries are recommending their Governments putting these vaccines on hold like this or would an answer to that be speculation. Some EU countries are blocking the AstraZeneca vaccine even though the numbers are low. And the Governments are taking the advice

Comment: As for AstraZeneca vaccine for example, [in EU and UK as of April 4th](https://www.ema.europa.eu/en/news/astrazenecas-covid-19-vaccine-ema-finds-possible-link-very-rare-cases-unusual-blood-clots-low-blood), there were 34 million vaccinated with the AstraZeneca vaccine and there were 222 blood clots. That means 0.0007% of vaccinated had blood clots. Not significant and could have been caused by something other than the vaccine. I had the Pfizer vaccine and that has similarly low percentage figures.

Comment: Your link reports 6.8 million J&J doses with 6 blood clots. That's 0.00009%

Comment: @CareyGregory https://www.uptodate.com/contents/covid-19-vaccine-induced-immune-thrombotic-thrombocytopenia-vitt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of April 16, 2021, information about blood clots in people vaccinated with the Sputnik V and the CanSino COVID-19 vaccines come from news articles and press releases.

Here is a link to an April 14, 2021 article in MedExpress that discusses the Sputnik V vaccine.

https://medicalxpress.com/news/2021-04-russia-sputnik-vaccine-blood-clots.html

A statement from the state-run Gamaleya Research Institute, which developed Sputnik V vaccine, is quoted as follows:

“A comprehensive analysis of adverse events during clinical trials and over the course of mass vaccinations with the Sputnik V vaccine showed that there were no cases of cerebral venous sinus thrombosis."

An April 14, 2021 article in the South China Morning Post discusses blood clots for the CanSino vaccine.

https://www.scmp.com/news/china/science/article/3129553/covid-19-vaccines-chinas-cansino-distances-itself-blood-clot

The articles quotes CanSino Biologics, manufacturer of the vaccine, as follows:

“In a filing to the Hong Kong stock exchange, the company said no serious adverse events related to blood clots had been reported among the almost 1 million doses of its COVID-19 vaccine that had been administered to date."

Based on past experience with surveillance of potential adverse effects of new drugs and vaccines, one must anticipate that information about blood clots for all of the COVID-19 vaccines will evolve (and change).

Comment: "there were no cases of cerebral venous sinus thrombosis" -- That's suspiciously narrow anatomy. How about systemic embolisms elsewhere?

Comment: @Carey Gregory The CDC and FDA paused the J&J vaccine because of six observed cases of central venous sinus thrombosis. This is described in the OP's first link and in more detail in the CDC public health alert.  https://emergency.cdc.gov/han/2021/han00442.asp  In the long run, a really good population-based study examining vaccination (and COVID-19) and the incidence of venous thrombosis (not limited to central venous sinus thrombosis) needs to be done, in my opinion.

Comment: See, that's what struck me as suspicious. Why they only denied CVTs and not venous thrombosis elsewhere?

Comment: @Carey Gregory  The CDC and FDA are looking at data from the Vaccine Adverse Event Reporting System, reported "spontaneously" by physicians and others.  VAERS reports are monitored to look for "unusual" events.  Central venous sinus thrombosis is "unusual."   The European Medicines Agency also focused on "unusual blot clots" (including central venous sinus thrombosis) in its review of AstraZeneca.  https://www.ema.europa.eu/en/news/astrazenecas-covid-19-vaccine-ema-finds-possible-link-very-rare-cases-unusual-blood-clots-low-blood   See also April 16, 2021 New England Journal of Medicine.